# How do I modify options of a terminal program?

Tags: linux, terminal, bioinformatics

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYKjJ.png)

See Terminal picture here above. How do I modify the "allowed options" when I run the program? E.g.: how can I modify the error rate?

I think you shouldn't focus on what the program is, it is just a syntax question. I've tried placing "--error_rate arg 0.1" at different places in the line when I run the program, but it won't run.

It is probably extremely easy, I'm just starting on the terminal.

Comment: Sorry, got wrong end of the stick. Try `--error_rate 0.1` and fix the `-depth` issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the value of the flag "error_rate" to "0.05", you can use:

```
./sim_reads --error_rate 0.05 yourfile1 yourfile2
```

If you additionally want to set the flag "depth" to "30", you can use:

```
./sim_reads --error_rate 0.05 --depth 30 yourfile1 yourfile2
```

Note:

- in both examples, *yourfile1* and *yourfile2* **must** be replaced with actual filenames according to the usage of your program. You can not literally type "yourfile1".
- You **must** use two dashes. You can not use a single dash in front of the flag.
- You **must not** include the literal word "arg". It is present in the flag list to show where to place the argument.

This is standard convention for almost all Unix tools.